# How do I start up my PC?

Tags: windows-10, boot, safe-mode, start-screen

My PC is stuck in the Welcome screen forever. After I give my password, the Welcome wheel is spinning forever.

Now I looked up the problem in the web, it was told to **Shift+Restart** the PC, and then start the startup repair option.

The startup repair could not solve the problem. It said *Start Repair could not solve your problem* . Then I tried to boot the PC via Safe Mode, but, here, after giving my password, after the Welcome wheel spins for a while, a black screen appears, where only the cursor moves. Nothing else happens.

Before all these, I changed the Language of all users via Registry Editor, and installed Battlefield 1 which I downloaded via torrent.

***How do I solve this?***

Comment: The use of torrent doesn't directly indicate piracy, It's a very valid technology which allows large files to be distributed easily. Don't blame the road for the bad driver. ;) Secondly, if there is a crack/hack used, it's VERY possible that it also contained a virus, which could disrupt the booting of windows.

Comment: I did not install a crack or a patch.

Comment: Windows booted fine. but yeah, something with actual user account... tried booting in Safe mode, and wait much time? maybe something is booting reeeally slow. Maybe some kind of viruses.

Comment: @Strepsils there's no virus. I use paid antivirus. Might be what you say. And after trying to boot in Safe Mode, after the welcome screen, I am stuck at a completely black screen.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 is stuck at logon screen.
This could be mostly because of user profile corruption or some unknown services at start up preventing the user to sign in as normal.

This has nothing to do with bootrec,
Bootrec command are used if the computer does not boot up. In your case the windows is booting fine, but just not sign in.

I suggest you to try
Disconnecting all external devices connecting to the PC.
Boot in the recovery boot, use the command prompt and create a new user account.

Answer (score 0):

Using Windows 10 installation media, re-boot the system from the media:
1.  At Windows – Install screen, click “Repair your computer”.
2.  Select Troubleshoot - Advances options – Command Prompt.
3.  Try to using “sfc /scannow” to check/repair system files.
4.  Try to using “Bootrec /FixMbr” to scan/find boot issue.
5.  Try to using “Bootrec /FixBoot” to write a new boot sector on the hard disk if Windows detects damage.

Reference “**Use Bootrec.exe in the Windows RE to troubleshoot startup issues**” for detail steps:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927392/use-bootrec-exe-in-the-windows-re-to-troubleshoot-startup-issues